# Google play alpha publish goes to prod?

Tags: android, testing, google-play, publishing

I already have a published app on Google play.

I'd like to publish the next genration app for alpha testing.

I upload an APK in the alpha testers tab. After the upload finishes, I click 'Save draft', and see it there, with the correct version - having the correct status: 'Draft in Alpha'.

**BUT**, when refreshing the browser, the same apk moves to the PRODUCTION tab, with the status 'Draft in Prod'.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure you press the **Publish Now** button (Just above the tabs)

Comment: Had the same exact problem. A refresh does move it to Draft in Prod, but if you click Publish Now (and do not refresh) it publishes your alpha apk.

Comment: Works, but I still think it's a bug. If I'm not pushing the publish button, the apk needs to stay as alph draft and not move to prod draft.